# How to use custom keywords in SVN

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, visualsvn-server

I'm using a VisualSVN server and TortoiseSVN client. I have set the properties

```
svn:keywords = Author Id Revision LastChangedDate Copyright
copyright = (c) 2009 Foo Company.
```

Then, when I try to use these properties in the header file (including the custom property Copyright), I do it like:

```
/******************************************************************************
* $Id$
* 
* $Author$
*
* $Revision$
*
* $LastChangedDate$
*
* $Copyright$
******************************************************************************/
```

Every property is getting substituted right, except for the Copyright. What am I still missing?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Prior to SVN 1.8, custom keywords were unsupported by SVN.

Here are the supported keywords, and how they work.
http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.advanced.props.special.keywords.html

Custom keywords had been a feature request for some time.
http://subversion.tigris.org/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=890

The feature was finally added as of SVN 1.8 (thanks MarkusSchaber).
https://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.8#custom-keywords

Comment: Thanks for the information. It seems that there are patches that allow to do that, so perhaps this will work in future releases.

Comment: It works in SVN 1.8, see https://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.8#custom-keywords

Comment: @MarkusSchaber Thanks for pointing that out.  Updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You need the correct syntax.
i.e. it's not `$Id$`, you need `$Id:  $`. Then the value gets put here: `$Id: value $`

Comment: Seems you're right and I was wrong. I'm sure I used to have trouble with $Id$ etc. Maybe I had a dodgy SVN client.

Answer (score -1):

I think that keywords are case sensitive.
Try this:

```
svn:keywords = Author Id Revision LastChangedDate Copyright
Copyright = (c) 2009 Foo Company.
```

Comment: I'm missing something else because it still doesn't work. Thanks!