# SVN Custom Keyword Patches

Tags: svn, patch

Are there any patches out there for custom keywords in SVN?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont know if this will address your situation -- but you may want to look at this discussion from SO

[How to use custom keywords in SVN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410029/how-to-use-custom-keywords-in-svn)