# SVN Checkout with @version $Id$ set

Tags: php, svn, version

I develop in Subversion, and at the top of each and every PHP file I have the following comment block;

```
<?php 

if(!defined('BASEPATH')) die('Direct Script Access is not allowed.');

/**
 * Project Name
 *
 * @author Sheldon Lendrum
 * @version $Id$
 * @copyright __MyCompanyName__, 29 January, 2011
 * @package default
 **/
```

What I would like to do is when exporting it( or even checking out on the main server, to set that $Id$ of the current head ?

I use Subversion on OSX and Debian for my primary web servers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the svn:keywords property on your files in your repository.

Check out [keyword documentation from the subversion book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.4/svn.advanced.props.special.keywords.html).

Other Stack Overflow questions you might find useful:

- [Fill @version tag with subversion in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295661/fill-version-tag-with-subversion-in-eclipse)
- [How to use custom keywords in SVN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410029/how-to-use-custom-keywords-in-svn)