# Including the file version information in SVN with maven

Tags: svn, cvs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SVN Checkout with @version $Id$ set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4835780/svn-checkout-with-version-id-set)

we are planning to move from CVS to SVN. In CVS, we used the following Annotations to maintain the version history.

```
@since 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT // File revision assigned my maven 
@version $Id: <user check-in the file with time stamp> $ // Tells last user modified the file.
```

Using the Maven updates version, we are updating the snapshot version for every release.

```
mvn --batch-mode release:update-versions -DdevelopmentVersion=1.2.0-SNAPSHOT
```

How can I maintain the version number of the file and user who have modified the file recently from the SVN with Maven.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4835780/svn-checkout-with-version-id-set

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with properties as described [here](http://www.startupcto.com/server-tech/subversion/setting-the-id-tag).